# Heroku Timeout::timeout not throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using heroku to host a ruby on rails application supporting an iOS app.  I have a request that might run long and I need to be able to catch the timeout before my request gets killed.  I'm using Timeout::timeout(15) to throw an error and handle it appropriately.  This works fine on my local and I can see the error being thrown and logged.  When I run the same code on heroku no error is logged.  I had the same problem when trying to use the rack timeout gem.

Is anyone else having a problem getting timeouts to run on Heroku?  I'm on cedar.

Comment: yes I'm having the exact same issue, very annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# app/controllers/index_controller.rb
require 'timeout'
Class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def timeout
    begin
      status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
        sleep(6)
        render :text => "will never be rendered"
      rescue Timeout::Error
        render :text => "timeout handled"
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/routes.rb

match '/timeout' => "index#timeout"
```

This works fine on heroku: http://young-gorge-7585.herokuapp.com

Comment: I see you have an open block `{` but no close?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using Rack::Timeout, designed for this very purpose.

https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout